# How can I programmatically check that I am running code in a notebook in julia?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, julia

I would need to programmatically check that I am running code in a jupyter notebook from `Julia`. One way would be using

`isdefined(Main, :IJulia)`

However this does not work for notebooks within vscode since they are run from outside IJulia is there a check that would work in this case as well?

Comment: What's the use case for that? In practice, it's going to be much more useful to e.g., dispatch printing and plotting over the output MIME type and so on, if that's the problem

Comment: It may be that that is the way to go. The reason currently the dispatch is not used is that we want to allow for both Pluto and Jupyter support with the same signature however I am not sure if the Interact approach used with jupyter works with Pluto as well.

Comment: IIRC Pluto and IJulia want the same kind of MIME specialize of `Base.show()`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however we there is an interactive viewer that behaves differently in Pluto and Jupyter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `@__FILE__` this yields `REPL[_]` in Julia REPL, `In[_]` in Jupyter and "/path/to/file.jl#==#hashocde" in Pluto so the test could be:

```
match(r"^In\[[0-9]*\]$", @__FILE__) != nothing
```

and in VSCode:
[image]

so you can check if the file ends with ".ipynb" if you want to find VSCode. Moreover: `isdefined(Main, :VSCodeServer)` yields `true` if you run from VSCode.

Comment: Thanks this works for my case!